# Запуск Котлин ktor на обычном хостинге

Tags: kotlin, хостинг, backend, ktor

Сейчас для новой работы изучаю бэкенд на Котлине с использованием библиотеки ktor. До этого создавал только локальный сервер на своем компьютере встроенными средствами программной среды intellij idea, или для хостинга использовал только php в бэкенде. Вот возник вопрос - возможно ли запустить сделанное творение на котлине на обычном хостинге вроде hostiman, timeweb и так далее? И если да, то как?

Попытки найти что-то в интернете приводило к статьям совсем о другом, вроде node js на хостинге.
Простите, если всё-таки плохо искал или плохо сформулировал вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, ktor приложения можно хостить так же как и обычные java-приложения. Нужен хостинг с сервером Java приложений.

Вот тут описано как заливать на Google App Engine и Heroku
https://ktor.io/servers/deploy.html